# Webserver and application server communcation

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, weblogic

We have `web application`,that contains both `dynamic` and `static` contents. As our client want Static content in `tomcat` and dynamic content in `web logic` . Is it possible to do this type of  `configuration` , how we could achieve this ? what are the support connectors or support for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: Make sure that the URLs for the static content can be statically filtered (e.g. place static images in a /image path) and configure the webserver to serve everything that matches this path from static directories, forward the rest to the appserver.

Or vice versa: Filter the dynamic content and serve the rest statically.

Comment: in dynamic content we have perl and CGI ,servlet .are you sure it work on Web logic .please let me know how do we get wrok

Comment: it's best maintainable if you have distinct URL (patterns) for different kinds of content - this will work with whatever technology you use. You can even address your static content from a completely different host (e.g. CDN) and don't worry about having it deployed to the same server where you deploy your dynamic content. Just add absolute addressing to the static content's URL